# How to have multiple mouse cursors or to simulate multiple mouse but not moving my cursor in the same computer?

Tags: operating-system, mouseevent, mouse

Recently I have some tasks on my computer that have to use the mouse cursor automatically, which are like some automated scripts. However, I only have one computer with two monitors, so I hope to work on one of the screens and then let my automated tasks be doing on the other screen with more than two mouse cursors or even more.

So my question is if it is possible to have multiple mouse cursors in a single computer and I can control these cursors by some programming languages like C, C++ or Python? Or, is it possible to simulate some mouse events on the computer but not moving my only mouse cursor? My operating system can be Windows 10 or Ubuntu 18.04 desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mouse cursor is nothing more than a specific area on screen where you can perform multiple actions. Usually you have a pointer that tells you where the active area is on that specific moment.

The exception is on a touch screen where a cursor is not visible because your finger touching the screen is the cursor position.

If you connect more than one device to control your cursor, only one pointer will be visible, but you might want more than one user operating a computer. [More details](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/install-multiple-mouse-and-keyboard-on-one-computer/)

For short, yes, it's possible to control more than one cursor at a time, and yes you can run some scripts or some RPA tools to perform that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I found this utility: https://www.mousemux.com/
it looks like prefect fit for you. It pairs mouse + keyboard to a user. Each user can work independently. However this is still beta version and it doesn't work with all programs.

Comment: It looks awesome! Thank you!