# Is there a way to simulate multiple mouse pointers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly, I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535703/how-to-have-multiple-mouse-cursors-or-to-simulate-multiple-mouse-but-not-moving) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237155/multiple-mouse-pointers) post here StackOverflow. However, most of the information in these posts is either severely outdated or not applicable to my use case.

I would like to know if it is possible to simulate `n` mouse pointers with `n` different instances of Python. That is, I would like to be able to run as many mouse pointers on my screen as possible. All of these mouse pointers would be controlled by the same script, but would still be doing all their work independently of each other.

Is it possible to create such an application using Python?

Comment: Does your desktop environment even support multiple mouse pointers? I think that e.g. if I plug multiple mice into my desktop, they will all control the same pointer.

Comment: @larsks Sure, but I know it's possible to have different "fake" mouse inputs available. Botting clients for some games seem to make use of this as well.